# Does serialization not always end in serializing primitive types?

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

I'm using Kryo for creating game-saves in code I'm working on.

Using the default serializer, FieldSerializer, I serialize one massive POJO.
It's a class that contains other classes I've created and primitive types.

The entire state of my game world is saved and loaded completely correct without creating any custom serializers.

- Are not all class trees originally built up from primitive data
  types?
- Why would you need any other serializer?

The only thing I can think of is improving disk space or speed of serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in a perfect world, you should only serialize pojos, and pojos should be a 'tree of primitives data types'.. But it's not so easy.

In order to be fast, Kryo doesn't use java serialization by default. It have his own serializer, `FieldSerializer`, which introspect instances and serialize it fields by fields. This serializer doesn't use default method like `readResolve` `writeReplace`, and fail to restore some objects behaviors.

For example, imagine a simple POJO, which own a `Date` property. This "primitive datatypes" doesn't have any field serializable (there are all marked as transient) : his serialization process is done through `readObject` or `writeObject` : The default FieldSerializer will not work.

If your POJO has a collection property, and you create an instance with `Collections.emptyList()`, then this can work.. or not : The "emptyList" collection should be a singleton, and this behavior is done through a `readResolve` method. The FieldSerializer doesn't know about it.

Kryo come with a set of defaults serializers which can handle this kind of types, but sometimes, you have to create your own to handle a class with a particular behavior. But usually, you create a serializer in order to improve the speed of classes which you serialize often, not because Kryo is not able to serialize them.

Kryo come with a special serializer, `JavaSerializer` or `ExternalizableSerializer` which use the default java serialization but they prevent Kryo to "see" inner fields and you loose all the benefits of using Kryo.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the Date example you gave completely. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html implements Serializable, but doesn't contain any fields.   Could you explain the same example in a different manner?

Comment: Look at the source for the class Date : all fields are marked as transient, the serialization is done through `readObject` and `writeObject`. You can't just "copy" the field, like the Kryo `FieldSerializer`. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Date.java